# Append method not appending to all elements

Tags: javascript

I have created my own JS library. In that i am trying to define append method like this:

```
append: function (els) {
var elChild = document.createElement('span');
elChild.innerHTML = els;
for(i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
    this[i].appendChild(elChild);
}
}
```

Now i am calling this append method in my script tag of HTML page like this:

```
<body>
<h1 class="first_heading">hello</h1>
<h1 class="second_heading">hi</h1>
<button>Test Me</button>
</body>
<script>
dome.get('h1').append('<p>some text</p>');
</script>
```

But the problem is all h1 tags not appending the paragraph text. Only last h1 is appending paragraph text. Any solution?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: use  `document.querySelector("h1")` or `document.querySelectorAll("h1")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild:

> The **`Node.appendChild()`** method adds a node to the end of the list of children of a specified parent node. If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, `appendChild()` moves it from its current position to the new position

In other words, the same node can't appear in multiple places in a document. You have to call `document.createElement('span')` separately for each child you want to create.

Comment: Great.. Worked for me. Just Great. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned `this` this corresponds to the object in scope. In this scenario, it is the window object. Here is a simple way to append the string to all headers

```js
  function append(tagname, text) {
    // get all tag names
    all_t = document.getElementsByTagName(tagname);
    // loop through and append the string to the inner html of each tag
    for (var x = 0; x < all_t.length; ++x) {
      all_t[x].innerHTML += text
    }

  }
  append('h1', '<p>some text</p>')
```

```html
<h1 class="first_heading">hello</h1>
<h1 class="second_heading">hi</h1>
<button id="b">Test Me</button>
```